# Method Invoke with complex parameter dynamically (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to invoke `method1` in `class1  dynamically`. I don't want to use `Prm class` directly. How to send `p parameter dynamically`. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22971/Casting-and-Passing-Anonymous-Types) is a way but i could'nt manage

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplicationMethodCall
{
    public class Prm
    {
        public string p1 { get; set; }
        public long p2 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Class1
    {
        public string Method1(Prm p)
        {
            return "Hello world";
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var ass = Assembly.LoadFrom("abc.dll");
  var business = ass.CreateInstance("WindowsFormsApplicationMethodCall.Class1");
  var mInfo = business.GetType().GetMethod("Method1");
  var anonymParameter = new { p1 = "", p2 = 2 };
  mInfo.Invoke(business,new object[]{ anonymParameter});
  //var res = mInfo.TolerantCast(new { p1 = "", p2 = 2 });
  //var param = new Dictionary<string,object>();
  //param.Add("p", result);                
}
```

I found this error :
Object of type `` <>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.Int32] `` cannot be converted to type

Comment: must be create object parameter same type Prm
this code create anonymous object
"var anonymParameter = new { p1 = "", p2 = 2 };"

Comment: c#/.Net is type safe. The functions only accepts Prm objects, so you have to pass a Prm object.

Comment: I know this. Actually i have method, class and dll names as string. And there are parameters as List<string>. And i want to invoke method1 dynamically.

Comment: try use 
dynamic anonymParameter  = ass.CreateInstance("WindowsFormsApplicationMethodCall.Prm");
anonymParameter.p1="";
or 
var anonymParameter  = ass.CreateInstance("WindowsFormsApplicationMethodCall.Prm");
anonymParameter.GetType().GetProperty("p1").SetValue(anonymParameter,"");
anonymParameter.GetType().GetProperty("p2").SetValue(anonymParameter,2);
anonymParameter.p2=2;

Comment: yes, I think there is'nt another way. Can you copy these code in your answer.

Comment: Can you provide some `Demo code` that you want?

Answer (score 2):

**Create Instance From Class "Prm" and use it Instead**

```
var anonymParameter = new { p1 = "", p2 = 2 };
```

> to

```
var anonymParameter  = ass.CreateInstance("WindowsFormsApplicationMethodCall.Prm");
anonymParameter.GetType().GetProperty("p1").SetValue(anonymParameter,""); 
anonymParameter.GetType().GetProperty("p2").SetValue(anonymParameter,2);
```

Comment: yes. I create instance and set value via GetPropeties() and SetValue()

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an object of type `Prm`:

```
var parameter = new Prm { p1 = "", p2 = 2 };
mInfo.Invoke(business,new object[]{ parameter });
```